# SOLVED - $wp_admin_bar and AJAX calls

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin-bar

Something weird is happening in my class. Basically I'm trying to manipulate the `$wp_admin_bar` through AJAX but when I receive the response I get a NULL value.
Although debugging the global when my method is initialised, I get the right values.

My class:

```
class my_class(){

   var $DefaultBar;
   public function __construct(){
      $this->initialise();
   }

   public function initialise(){
      add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', array( $this , 'admin_bar_load' )); //or admin_bar_menu
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_the_page',  array( $this ,'get_the_page') );
   }

   public function admin_bar_load(){
      global $wp_admin_bar;

      //here I assign the value to the class variable declared before
      $GLOBALS['default_bar'] = $wp_admin_bar;
      //if I var_dump here, I get all the values

   }

   public function get_the_page(){

      global $default_bar;

      ob_start();
      include 'inc/forms/my_page.php';
      $response = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
      wp_send_json($response);

   }
}
```

In my page, called with action `get_the_page()` through AJAX, on `$(document).ready` I've placed then:

```
<?php var_dump($default_bar); ?>
```

### EDIT / SOLUTION

I realised there's a timing issue about calls. I just changed the logic of my class.

Comment: I suppose the admin bar isn't rendered in AJAX calls, so `admin_bar_load()` will be loaded when you request the page, but not when making the ajax call

Comment: hey @kero, thank you so much. I suppose that too, but how to achieve it then? Do you have an idea?

Comment: The request the admin bar is rendered in is not the same request that handled the AJAX request, you can't set a variable in one request then read it in another like that, that's not how PHP works

Comment: Alright @TomJNowell but to manipulate the `$wp_admin_bar` I have 2 ways, as far as I know: `wp_before_admin_bar_render` and `admin_bar_menu` hooks. So do you say that I should hook those into the wp_ajax_ function?

Comment: Take a step back. Why do you want/need the admin bar in the AJAX call? You might have to test this, I'm not sure if simply setting `show_admin_bar` to `true` could solve this

Comment: So, I need to manipulate the admin bar with several other functions. What I'm interested in, is the method `get_nodes()` to store the default admin bar before changing it. Of course, in my page I have a form.

Answer (score -1):

That's not how PHP requests work, you cannot set a variable in one request, then read it in another request. It isn't like a Node or Python application where the program runs continuously in the background, every request is a blank slate.

So, to make it work, in the first request you need to put it somewhere that the second request can read from, for which there are several options:

- Cookies
- User meta
- Options/Transients

As it's a logged in user, and persisting across sessions would make sense, user meta seems the most logical choice, via `update_user_meta` and `get_user_meta`

Comment: This is a community that works on supportive answers, it wouldn't be an "exchange" otherwise. Giving lectures doesn't help anybody, even proven that you could know the code better than others.

Comment: @huraji every answer is in its way a mini lecture, that doesn't really help me improve the answer though, but I have tried to make it more concise. One could even argue the question should be closed as off topic as the root problem is fundamental to PHP not WP. If you want to discuss community and supportive answers further though, there's a meta stack for those kinds of discussions